# C# analogy for Python's yield from

Tags: c#, python, generator, yield-return

If I would like to merge two generators in one

```py
def gen1():
    for i in range(5):
        yield i

def gen2():
    for i in 'asdf':
        yield i

def gen():
    yield from gen1()
    yield from gen2()
```

or do some recursive generator

```py
def gen(arg):
    if arg == 1:
        yield from gen(0)
    for i in range(10):
        yield i
```

in Python I'll use `yield from`. Is there any alternative how to do similar stuff in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no syntax sugar for combining two iterators for `yield return`.

You can either use `Enumerable.Concat` if you just need to iterate them in sequence or write code to iterate the sequence and `yield return` each element.